# SharePoint 2019 On Premise Modern Site- Change Branding text from SharePoint to something else

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2019

I have SP 2019 On-Premise Modern site where I want to change Branding text from SharePoint to something else. How could  I do it?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following css in master page to change Branding text from SharePoint to something else.

```
<style type="text/css">
.o365cs-nav-brandingText{ display: none !important;}
</style>
```

But it only works in classic page, which is not working in Modern Experience.

Unfortunately, in Modern Experience, you can't customize the default list page to add JS or custom CSS as we did in classic mode.

New Modern page doesn't have any master page associated and it has been created using the Theme's and it has no option to customize anything like what you did with your classic site.

Answer (score 0):

I want to share answer on the same question provided by Lee_MSFT.
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/262946/63460

> You could create SPFx Application Customizer to inject custom CSS to hide element.
>
> Check below threads for demos.
>
> https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/master/samples/react-application-injectcss
>
> https://tahoeninjas.blog/2018/05/08/inject-custom-css-on-sharepoint-modern-pages-using-spfx-extensions/