# Hide Share button on modern command bar

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience

I'm just getting in to customizing the modern interface in SharePoint Online for a new project. If this has been answered repeatedly before, my Google-fu may be off.

We've disabled sharing on a site, but the Share button still shows up when a file is selected - granted, the only option available is "People with existing access" but this is confusing people. So we'd like to hide this button all together.

[image]

It sounds like it was possible to do this in the classic interface, but I haven't found anything about doing it in the modern interface.

I've tried using CSS, which the modern interface doesn't support. I've also started looking into PnP Custom Actions, but I haven't found anything specific about hiding a built-in button with that.

Any pointers, thoughts, links to articles that I've clearly missed ... all welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You could create [SPFx Application Customizer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/using-page-placeholder-with-extensions) to inject custom CSS to hide element.

Check below threads for demos.

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/master/samples/react-application-injectcss

https://tahoeninjas.blog/2018/05/08/inject-custom-css-on-sharepoint-modern-pages-using-spfx-extensions/

Comment: A ready-made solution in github https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/main/samples/js-command-hide-commands. The hide/unhide is configurable through a custom list without deploying a new code.

Comment: The only issue with this approach is that, there is fluctuation while loading the page. i.e these options are first shown for a sec and then hidden. Is there any approach to overcome this?

Comment: No. There is no easy way to overcome it. Hope Microsoft would release a proper API to play around with these buttons.