# Modifiy HTML, CSS, JS, in Sharepoint 2019 On Premises Modern Site

Tags: modern-experience, css, html

I am new to SharePoint 2019 On Premises, I would like if someone can help me to know how I should do to modify a modern page of a site, I would like the basics, change the font, adjust the size of the icons, location, I have knowledge of HTML, CSS and JS, but I don't know where to start to see the code, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Use SPFx

Create SPFx Application Customizer to inject custom CSS

See: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/262946/63460