# SharePoint 2019 On-Premise branding

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have a Site Collection that has branding applied within the  Master Gallery Template library, what I need to do is copy that site collection's look and feel over to another server.  I have the new Site Collection on the new server configured with the Site Collection Features and site features for publishing.  I've copied over all the site content types and site columns.  I then copied over everything in the master gallery template library and made sure everything was published, but the new site is still not applying the branding.  It's like it is not recognizing the css file.  I am not sure what else I am missing and how to get this to work.  I even created a design package and then imported that design package to the new site and still nothing.

The original codes was compiled using Visual Studio.  Does this mean I can't copy the compiled code of master pages and css to another location?  Or do I need to compile for the new location?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few potential issues that might be causing this:

CSS Files Not Working: SP2019 CSS Bug (https://blog.stefan-gossner.com/2018/11/30/common-issue-sp2019-items-in-document-libraries-are-downloaded-with-mime-type-application-octet-stream-rather-than-the-accurate-one/). This issue has been fixed, so ensure your server is updated with the latest patches.

Modern vs Classic Experience: CSS in the master page only works in the classic page and does not work in the Modern Experience.

Compiled Code: It’s possible that you might need to recompile the code for the new location. This is because the compiled code might have hard-coded references or dependencies that are specific to the original location.

Bug: https://blog.stefan-gossner.com/2018/11/30/common-issue-sp2019-items-in-document-libraries-are-downloaded-with-mime-type-application-octet-stream-rather-than-the-accurate-one/

See: [SharePoint 2019 On Premise Modern Site- Change Branding text from SharePoint to something else](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/262628/sharepoint-2019-on-premise-modern-site-change-branding-text-from-sharepoint-to)

And: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6d40c7ef-e243-441e-b7e4-65fd57a4ca44/sharepoint-2019onpremise-site-branding